# Как работает метод find() у контейнера set в C++?

Tags: c++, set, find, бинарный-поиск

В set элементы по стандарту становятся в порядке возрастания и при этом удаляются дубликаты.

Как именно find() ищет в set нужный нам элемент? Он проходится по порядку начиная с первого элемента и сопоставляет значения? Или же использует алгоритм бинарного поиска, так как элементы отсортированы и это становится возможным?

Просто алгоритм бинарного поиска работает гораздо быстрее и в данном конкретном случае кажется более логичным.

Мне интересно, продумали ли разработчики C++ всё настолько серьезно или в этом нет абсолютно никакого смысла и за бинарный поиск в set отвечает какой-то другой метод или функция?

Comment: Вообще-то, продумали. И очень тщательно. Кстати, как говорится, учите матчасть: [***Complexity**:
Logarithmic in the size of the container*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find).

Comment: С матчастью у меня все прекрасно) За сайт большое спасибо, не знал, что где-то можно посмотреть сложность стандартных методов.

Comment: *не знал, что где-то можно посмотреть сложность стандартных методов* — вообще-то в стандарте. Или в любой более-менее серьезной книге по стандартной библиотеке...

Comment: *"С матчастью у меня все прекрасно"* Вас бы тогда тут не было. :Р За логарифмическое время линейный поиск не может работать, значит тут не он. Открываем https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set - "usually implemented as Red–black trees". Тут двоичный поиск не потому, что set отсортированный, а потому что он - дерево.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По стандарту set является ассоциативным контейнером, как map, только без значений, только ключи.

Стандарт не требует линейного расположения элементов.

Стандарт требует логарифмической сложности для алгоритма поиска.

Например в GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) set реализован на основе красно-черного дерева. У него точно сложность поиска логарифмическая.

[image]

Если интересно, то вот [ссылка](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf) на стандарт 2020 года.

Comment: Стандарт скорее налагает ограничения на свойства контейнера. На элементах должен быть задан порядок, не требуется хранить элементы контейнера в непрерывном куске памяти, сложность операций поиска, вставки, удаления должна быть логарифмической. Откуда уже вытекает, что `std::set` может быть реализован на основе красно-чёрного дерева, но не обязан.

Comment: Поправил ответ)